# Fading Ball in Roblox Lua

Tags: loops, lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a ball that fades to 1 transparency and then back to 0. 
Here's my code:

```
ball = script.Parent
trans = 0
while true do 
if trans < 1 then
    while trans < 1 do
        ball.Transparency = trans
        wait(0.1)
        trans = trans + 0.1 
    end
end
if trans == 1 then
    while trans <= 1 and trans >=0 do
        ball.Transparency = trans 
        wait(0.1)
        trans = trans -0.1 
    end
end
end
```

The ball did fade away but never comes back. At this point the game will just freeze up. Any solutions to this? Thanks!

Update : So I tried the following code today and it works fine but when I replace if ball.Transparency == 1 with trans == 1 on the if statement, the same issue occurs. Please explain this thanks!

```
while true do
ball = script.Parent
trans = 0
for i=0, 1, 0.1 do
    trans = i
    wait(0.1)
    ball.Transparency = trans
end
if ball.Transparency == 1 then
    for i = 1, 0, -0.1 do
        trans = i
        wait(0.1)
        ball.Transparency = trans
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point precision:

`0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1`

does *not* equal

`1`

I am not sure why that is not a factor when you assign the `trans` value to `ball.Transparency`.

Two things:

1) `if tostring(trans) == “1.0” then` works.

2) Better yet: why even check there if trans == 1? Of course it will, because the for loop right before that guarantees it.

Also, careful with your use of `while true`...it is likely why your program “freezes”.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used while true because I want to make it go on forever. I think using wait in between them will make it fine.

Comment: I replaced if ball.Transparency all together with if true and it works perfectly. :D